# "To be" or "for being"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Hello everybody, glad you invited me. I'm so happy **to be/for being** here.

What is a better option to use? Is there any rule in deciding which to choose and when? I mean, not only in this example.

Does maybe it depend on the previous adjective or something else?

Comment: "To be here" is the better alternative, but I don't have a technical English reason to give you.

Answer (score 4):

This is the sentence that you want to use:

> I'm so happy **to be** here.

This sentence should normally be avoided:

> I'm so happy **for being** here.

I can think of no real syntactical reason why **for being** is wrong, but it's not idiomatic and would not normally be used. (I've never encountered it before, but that doesn't mean it hasn't been used by somebody, somewhere.)

Unfortunately, I can't give a better answer than that.

---

I'm afraid it gets even more confusing.

Some things simply don't pair well with other things. However, it appears to mostly come down to common usage and what is used and sounds natural rather than there actually being specific rules in every case.

Following are all examples of things that do and don't sound right. If you look only at the syntax, there appears to be no objective pattern.

> ✗ I am *happy* **for being** . . .
>   ✓ I am *happy* **to be** . . .
>
> ✓ I am *sorry* **for disturbing** . . .
>   ✓ I am *sorry* **to disturb** . . .
>
> ✗ I had *thought* **for visiting** . . .
>   ✓ I had *thought* **to visit** . . .
>
> ✓ I *listen* **for singing** . . .
>   ✗ I *listen* **to sing** . . .
>
> ✗ I *try* **for singing** . . .
>   ✓ I *try* **to sing** . . .
>
> ✗ I have *tried* **for seeing** . . .
>   ✓ I have *tried* **to see** . . .
>
> ✓ I am *crazy* **for trying** . . .
>   ✓ I am *crazy* **to try** . . .
>
> ✗ I am *struggling* **for thinking**
>   ✓ I am *struggling* **to think**

---

I would be happy if somebody else could come up with a more coherent explanation for all of this rather than "it just sounds right or wrong."